# Parent Element does not fill on Hover State

Tags: html, css, hover, height

I am having an issue with a hover state on .socialheader and I can't seem to figure it out. I want the social header to fill up on a hover event but it only fills to the height of the images inside the header. What could I change so that it fills up the entire height?

I have included a jsfiddle link. [http://jsfiddle.net/theflyingmouse/q43co9tk/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/theflyingmouse/q43co9tk/)

```css
.headeractions {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: rgb(51, 132, 165);
    overflow: hidden;
}


.requestheader {
    background-color: rgb(12, 109, 149);
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.requestheader:hover {

 background-color: rgb(9, 78, 107);
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.requesttitle {
    margin: 0;
}


.socialheader {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.socialheader:hover {
 background-color: rgb(9, 78, 107);
 transition: .2s;
}


.socialbutton {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="headeractions">
  <div class="requestheader"><h3>Request a Quote</h3></div><div class="socialheader">
   <div class="socialbutton"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kPJlZ3U.png"></div><div class="socialbutton"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kPJlZ3U.png"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is the correct JSfiddle right here. My apologies. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/theflyingmouse/q43co9tk/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this instead? http://jsfiddle.net/q43co9tk/7/

just use display table and table-cell

```
.headeractions{display: table;}
.requestheader{display: table-cell;}
.socialheader{display: table-cell;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/q43co9tk/6/

```
.socialheader {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 22px 0 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This padding pushes the .requestheader div down. I need these two divs to be the same height.

Comment: Then adjust the padding to fit your design? I've updated my answer.

Comment: This is definitely a way of solving the problem. I'm not sure if I understand why when I set the hover state to a parent div that the size of the hover depends on the child. I figured that if a height was set to the parent div that the hover would fill the height amount stated.

Comment: Because the hover state is set to activate on the parent div .socialheader not the socialbutton div.

Comment: this is how it would look with the hover on the socialbuttons http://jsfiddle.net/q43co9tk/8/

Comment: Thank you for your help. Though it did not fix quite exactly what I needed, the .socialbuttons comment made me realize flaws in my design. Cheers.